# How to get rid of Excel pop up prompt when attempt to open an image? Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, popups, security-warning

How can i disable the popup warning when i attempt to open an image w/ my Excel spreadsheet?  The button is hyper linked with relative path to the current directory, and each button is linked to either a .jpg or .png.  However, every time the link is clicked this warning pops up.  Is there a way to disable it in Excel?  This is Office 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the path to your trusted locations in the Excel options?
In Office 2007 (not sure about 2010 but prob the same) click on the Office button-->Excel Options-->Trust Center-->Trust Center Settings-->Trusted Locations-->Add new location...

Alternatively you can turn the pop up warning message off but going to : Office button-->Excel Options-->Trust Center-->Trust Center Settings-->Message Bar

Comment: tried the first option but did not work still pops up. will try the second

Comment: i turn the pop up warning off using second method.  did not work.